# Elasticsearch Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_write_pending','bad write retry) while using python elasticsearch_dsl bulk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am getting the following error while trying to insert docs using the bulk api (python elasticsearch_dsl) to AWS elastic search index. This error doesn't occur if I keep the chunk_size to a small number, say 10.

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_write_pending', 'bad write retry')]) caused by: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_write_pending', 'bad write retry')])
```

I am using awsauth to connect:

```
elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(
                    hosts=[{'host': ****, 'port': 443}],
                    http_auth=awsauth,
                    use_ssl=True,
                    verify_certs=True,
         connection_class=elasticsearch.connection.RequestsHttpConnection
                    )
```

I have the following versions of request installed.

```
requests (2.17.3)
requests-aws4auth (0.9)
```

What do I need to do avoid hitting this error? I can't really keep the payload too low.

Comment: does this problem solved?